# The List doesn't show up on the screen(Android Studio, Firebase)

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently developing the android application using the Android Studio, Firebase RealTime Database.

I'd like to make the List show up on the screen, but the List didn't show up.
I believe the application failed to read the data from the firebase.
(I made the debug and the value of the result.size() on the 
ResultsAdmin.java `Log.e("The read success: " ,"su"+result.size());` was 0. So, I think data transmission was conducted successfully, but the contents are empty.)

I really appreciate helpful suggestions as to what caused this situation.

Followings are the related codes.

activity_tests.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context=".Tests">


<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_tests" />



</RelativeLayout>
```

content_tests.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
>

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/test_listview">

</ListView>
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />
</FrameLayout>
```

test_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/item_imageView"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_imageView"
    android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
    android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize" />
<Button
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/item_button"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

ResultsAdmin.java(I abbreviate the import and package statements.)

```
public class ResultsAdmin extends AppCompatActivity {

private FirebaseDatabase database;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private DatabaseReference myRef;
private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ListView listView;
private ResultsAdmin.TestAdapter testAdapter;
ArrayList<String> result=new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_tests);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    database=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    myRef=database.getReference();
    listView=findViewById(R.id.test_listview);
    testAdapter=new ResultsAdmin.TestAdapter(ResultsAdmin.this,result);
    listView.setAdapter(testAdapter);
    getResults();
}

public void getResults(){

    myRef.child("Results").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            result.clear();
            for(DataSnapshot snapshot:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                result.add(snapshot.getKey()); //keyを取得している。Verbal～のこと。
            }
            testAdapter.dataList=result;
            testAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.e("The read success: " ,"su"+result.size());
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            Log.e("The read failed: " ,databaseError.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
class TestAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context mContext;
    ArrayList<String> dataList;
    public TestAdapter( Context context,ArrayList<String> list) {
        super(context, 0 , list);
        mContext = context;
        dataList = list;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        View listItem = convertView;
        if(listItem == null)
            listItem = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.test_item,parent,false);
       ((ImageView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.item_imageView)).setImageDrawable
(ContextCompat.getDrawable(mContext,R.drawable.ic_assessment_black_24dp));
        ((TextView)listItem.findViewById(R.id.item_textView)).setText(dataList.get(position));
        ((Button)listItem.findViewById(R.id.item_button)).setText("View");
        ((Button)listItem.findViewById(R.id.item_button)).setOnClickListener(new 
View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(ResultsAdmin.this,ResultsAdminDetailed.class);
                intent.putExtra("test",dataList.get(position));
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return listItem;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please post your database structure

Comment: There is a lot of code posted.  It is hard to tell which piece is failing without doing better debugging.  Using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler will indicate if the data was sent to the server.  Is this app using c# as well as java.  Then update tag to indicate it c#.  As well as Firebase.   It also looks like you are using unicode data which is useful info when asking for support.  It looks like you are clearing the list, setting the DGV to the empty list and then not filling the list.

Comment: @Ashish
Since this is the first time using the stackoverflow, I couldn't upload the image on the question space.But the following is the copy of the data structure on Firebase.

g-eval                                                                                
    --Results                                                                         
         --Verbal2                                                                    
               --~~~(uniqueuserid):2

Comment: Just post the url of image

Comment: @Ashish
Sorry, here is the url
https://ibb.co/f17ZncG

Comment: Please let me know if you want additional information about the app.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a listener to your list view or better use Recyclerview and 'OnScrolled listener' on it and make maintain a boolean to show progress bar and when data is loaded disable the progress bar. Recommened- Use pagination.